# How to display GreenDroid and TabHost in the same view?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, greendroid

I have imported a library named GreenDroid to show an action bar in the Top of the activity and i want to add a TabHost in the same activity but the first one needs to extends GDActivity and the second extends TabActivity. I tried to define the 2 bars in the same class but i can't  do multiple extends.i succeeded in displaying the 2 bars seperately but i want to make them in the same activity.

Comment: You can find a simple code on author's website, Cyril Mottier. http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend the GDTabActivity instead.

Comment: thx for answering me but i tried to extend the GDTabActivity but some methods that need to extend GDActivity became unrecognisable like setactionbarcontentview(). Can you help me with a little code or a tutorial that show how to display GreenDroid and TabHost in the same view! if you have it please help me because i'm trying to do it from several days :(